# Redirect Url to new Url with ignoring parameters in web.config

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config

i want to redirect my **old url (../Galary.aspx?cat=10)** to **new url(../jacket-style-gallery)** but it appends old parameters.

```
<rule name="rule9" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" /> 
  <conditions>  
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="cat=10" />  
  </conditions>  
  <action type="Redirect" url="./jacket-style-gallery" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

So it **redirect to "../jacket-style-gallery?cat=10"**

Answer (score 0):

If you want only  `Galary.aspx`

to be redirected then you should use:

```
<rule name="rule9" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="Galary.aspx" /> 
  <conditions>  
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="cat=10" />  
  </conditions>  
  <action type="Redirect" url="./jacket-style-gallery" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

I just tested on my server and it works.